# Redirect URL ending in certain `variable=value` query string, to `URL?variable` (i.e., strip `=value`)

Tags: redirects, apache, 301-redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to create a 301-rewrite for URLs ending with `?amp=1` to nearly the same URL and query string, just stripping the value (`=1`).

Examples:

- `https://example.com/?amp=1` should redirect to `https://example.com/?amp`
- `https://example.com/page/?amp=1` should redirect to `https://example.com/page/?amp`

I've managed to get the `RewriteCond` right to match only URLs ending with `?amp=1`, i.e.:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?amp=1$
```

but can't get the `RewriteRule` correct to go to the URL without the `=1` value.

Comment: You should also provide your `RewriteRule` in your question, even if it fails.

Comment: Should we consider that there might be other variables in the query string (e.g., `?amp=1&foo=qux&bar=quux`)?

Comment: In what context are you using these directives? Main server config/virtualhost or directory (`.htaccess`)?

Comment: "You should also provide your RewriteRule in your question, even if it fails."

What I have been able to produce, and test with online tools (not live server) is in the post.


"Should we consider that there might be other variables in the query string (e.g., ?amp=1&foo=qux&bar=quux)?"

Never any other variables. Only looking to address urls ending in ?amp=1 specifically.


"In what context are you using these directives? Main server config/virtualhost or directory (.htaccess)?"

In .htaccess


Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your `RewriteCond` is incidentally valid but fundamentally wrong. For the URL `https://example.com/?amp=1`, the characters `/?` are not part of the `%{QUERY_STRING}` value, which is `amp=1` in fact.
I said *'incidentally valid'* because in your regex, `/` is neutralized by `?`, so there is a match with `amp=1`.

To achieve your goal, in the simplest case, especially without the possibility of other variables in the query string, an *Apache* `.htaccess` file could include these directives:

```
# Tested with Apache httpd 2.4 on Debian 10
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^amp=1$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?amp [NE,R=301,L]
```